# delete item basket in shopping card (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I made a simple jquery shopping cart. if you press the `.addtobasket`, it will add the item to the basket and add the price.

but I also added to li span `deleteitembasket`. I try to make it remove the entire li from this item after pressing and subtract the price.

```
$("body").on("click", ".addtobasket", function (evt) {
    $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

    var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
    var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

    var suma = 0;
    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>"+nazwa+"</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>"+cena+" zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

    $("#koszyk").append(li);

    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function()
    {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });

$(".deleteitembasket").click(function() { ... ?? };

    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
});
```

EDIT:

this code works, but the sum in the cart is not refreshed automatically (after add new item)

```
    $("body").on("click", ".addtobasket", function (evt) {

    $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

    var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
    var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

    var suma = 0;
    var li = "<li class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>"+nazwa+"</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>"+cena+" zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

    $("#koszyk").append(li);

    $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function()
    {
        suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on('click','.deleteitembasket', function () {
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FSp1333, As you are creating deleteitembasket dynamically so you need to call this button's click event inside document.ready.

Try with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click','.deleteitembasket', function () {
         $(this).closest("li").remove();
     });
     $("#cena span").text("");
     $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function()
     {
         suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
     });
     $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
 });
```

and let me know is that case works for you?

Comment: Yes, this is remove my item. I can add to remove price this item. thank u!

Comment: great, All the best with next development :)

Comment: This work good, but this is not update my price now. (after add new item). can you change it?

Comment: without your code i can't. As i am not aware which logic you have applied!!